# Is there a tool to validate/check that package.json and package-lock.json are consistent?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

Sometimes people change `package.json` and forget to run `npm i` which will update `package-lock.json`, or `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are otherwise out of sync. This is an assumption not to be discussed/questioned here. I am looking for a tool that helps detect such cases.

Do you know of an npm feature or third-party tool that can sanity-check `package-lock.json`? For example, it should resolve all transitive dependencies, and check that they all are mentioned in the lock file with a version in the correct semver range. It should tell whether it would make sense to run `npm i` in order to update your lockfile, or also whether `npm ci` would get you all the dependencies required as defined in `package.json` (accounting for transitivity).

I thought that `npm --loglevel verbose install --dry-run` would be a reasonable candidate, but its output does not mention what it would do to `package-lock.json` in case it would be run without `--dry-run`. Of course one option would be to run `npm i` and then `git diff package-lock.json` (or similar), but that's dirty.

Answer (score 5):

`npm ls --depth 1` does these checks:

for example, this is the output:

```
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY fastify@^2.0.0
+-- foo@0.0.7 extraneous
`-- got@10.3.0
  +-- @sindresorhus/is@1.2.0
  +-- @szmarczak/http-timer@4.0.0
  +-- @types/cacheable-request@6.0.1
  +-- cacheable-lookup@0.2.2
  +-- cacheable-request@7.0.1
  +-- decompress-response@5.0.0
  +-- duplexer3@0.1.4
  +-- get-stream@5.1.0
  +-- lowercase-keys@2.0.0
  +-- mimic-response@2.0.0
  +-- p-cancelable@2.0.0
  +-- responselike@2.0.0
  +-- to-readable-stream@2.1.0
  `-- type-fest@0.9.0

npm ERR! missing: fastify@^2.0.0, required by asd@1.0.0
npm ERR! extraneous: foo@0.0.7
```

I get this doing:

```
npm init --yes
npm i got
npm i foo
// removed foo manually from package json
// added fastify manually to package json
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are suggesting to use `--depth 1`? It appears to me that then I won't see issues further down the dependency hierarchy. Am I mistaken? Note that I am not scared to see how deep the tree goes...

Comment: No, it is only a matter of the output. A complete depth tree could be very hard to read

Comment: When I run with depth `1` it doesn't show any errors, but when i run with depth `10` it does show the errors.

Comment: `npm ci` should also helps here: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5113